# Star rating : ignore mouseout if i trigger a certain function

Tags: javascript, jquery, font-awesome

I am trying to highlight starts, so when a user scrolls over star 3 it lights the 3 stars up but not the other 2 (total of 5 stars) and when I click a star I want to highlight them all even on mouse out, but because if they don't click the star I want the mouseout to still work, how can I do this? Here's my jquery:

```
$('document').ready(function()
{
    $('#1_star').on("mouseover", function(){
        $('#1_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x alert-success");
        $('#2_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x");
        $('#3_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x");
        $('#4_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x");
        $('#5_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x");
    });

    $('#2_star').on("mouseover", function(){
        $('#1_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x alert-success");
        $('#2_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x alert-success");
        $('#3_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x");
        $('#4_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x");
        $('#5_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x");
    });

    $('#3_star').on("mouseover", function(){
        $('#1_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x alert-success");
        $('#2_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x alert-success");
        $('#3_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x alert-success");
        $('#4_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x");
        $('#5_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x");
    });

    $('#4_star').on("mouseover", function(){
        $('#1_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x alert-success");
        $('#2_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x alert-success");
        $('#3_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x alert-success");
        $('#4_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x alert-success");
        $('#5_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x");
    });

    $('#5_star').on("mouseover", function(){
        $('#1_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x alert-success");
        $('#2_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x alert-success");
        $('#3_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x alert-success");
        $('#4_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x alert-success");
        $('#5_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x alert-success");
    });

    $('#5_star').on("mouseout", function(){ 
        $('#1_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x");
        $('#2_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x");
        $('#3_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x");
        $('#4_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x");
        $('#5_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x");   
    });

    $('#4_star').on("mouseout", function(){ 
        $('#1_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x");
        $('#2_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x");
        $('#3_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x");
        $('#4_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x");   
    });

    $('#3_star').on("mouseout", function(){ 
        $('#1_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x");
        $('#2_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x");
        $('#3_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x");   
    });

    $('#2_star').on("mouseout", function(){ 
        $('#1_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x");
        $('#2_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x");
    });

    $('#1_star').on("mouseout", function(){ 
        $('#1_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x");
    });

    $('.review_star').on("click", function(){

        var star = $(this).attr('id');

        $('#review_rating').val(star);

        if(star == 1){
            $('#1_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x alert-success");         
        }else if(star == 2){
            $('#1_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x alert-success");
            $('#2_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x alert-success");         
        }else if(star == 3){
            $('#1_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x alert-success");
            $('#2_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x alert-success");
            $('#3_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x alert-success");
        }else if(star == 4){
            $('#1_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x alert-success");
            $('#2_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x alert-success");
            $('#3_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x alert-success");
            $('#4_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x alert-success");
        }else if(star == 5){
            $('#1_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x alert-success");
            $('#2_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x alert-success");
            $('#3_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x alert-success");
            $('#4_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x alert-success");
            $('#5_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x alert-success");         
        }
    });
});
```

my html:

```
    <a href="javascript::void();" class="review_star" id="1"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x" id="1_star"></i></a>
    <a href="javascript::void();" class="review_star" id="2"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x" id="2_star"></i></a>
    <a href="javascript::void();" class="review_star" id="3"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x" id="3_star"></i></a>
    <a href="javascript::void();" class="review_star" id="4"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x" id="4_star"></i></a>
    <a href="javascript::void();" class="review_star" id="5"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x" id="5_star"></i></a>

    <form>
    <input type="hidden" id="review_rating" name="rating">
```

Also, is there a better way to do this as my code is redundant and has repetitive code

Comment: FYI, there is no element of type `'document'` usually in DOM

Comment: Would it be $(document) ?

Comment: Yes, it would. It does seem you might have overthought this, as well as the fact that you are repeating a lot of your code - that shows that you should first of try to get it to work with just a single mouseup and mousemove event - there is _so_ much going on here that you will hate debugging this simple, but complex looking feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) Your IDs shouldm't start with a number:**

=> Use for Eg `star_1` instead of `1_star`

**2) You don't need to change the full classes:**

```
$('#1_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x alert-success");
$('#2_star').attr("class", "fa fa-star-o fa-3x");
[...]
```

should be:

```
$('#star_1').addClass("alert-success");
$('#star_2').removeClass("alert-success");
[...]
```

**3) JQuery selectors can be grouped:**

```
$('#star_1').on("mouseover", function() {
    $('#star_1').addClass("alert-success");
    $('#star_2, #star_3, #star_4, #star_5').removeClass("alert-success");
});
```

**4) You can remove events with `.off()`:**

```
$('#star_1, #star_2, #star_3, #star_4, #star_5').off();
```

**SNIPPET:**

```js
$('#star_1, #star_2, #star_3, #star_4, #star_5').on("mouseover mouseout click", function (e) {
    for (var i =1; i<=5; i++) {
        if (i <= parseInt(this.id.replace("star_", "")) && e.type !== "mouseout") {
            $('#star_'+i).addClass("alert-success");
        } else {
            $('#star_'+i).removeClass("alert-success");
        }
    }
});
$('.review_star').on("click", function () {
    $('#star_1, #star_2, #star_3, #star_4, #star_5').off("mouseover mouseout");
    $('#review_rating').val($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

```css
.alert-success {
    color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
 <a href="#" class="review_star" id="1"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x" id="star_1"></i></a>
 <a href="#" class="review_star" id="2"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x" id="star_2"></i></a>
 <a href="#" class="review_star" id="3"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x" id="star_3"></i></a>
 <a href="#" class="review_star" id="4"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x" id="star_4"></i></a>
 <a href="#" class="review_star" id="5"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x" id="star_5"></i></a>

<form>
    <input type="hidden" id="review_rating" name="rating">
```

Comment: It''s mostly working, but if I click a star then click another the stars are still highlighted from the first click

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the incomplete answer, if I have time I'll provide more.

For now, check this approach to avoid redundant code:

```
<a href="#" class="review_star" data-nstar="1" id="1"><i class="fa fa- star-o fa-3x" id="1_star"></i></a>
<a href="#" class="review_star" data-nstar="2" id="2"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x" id="2_star"></i></a>
<a href="#" class="review_star" data-nstar="3" id="3"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x" id="3_star"></i></a>
<a href="#" class="review_star" data-nstar="4" id="4"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x" id="4_star"></i></a>
<a href="#" class="review_star" data-nstar="5" id="5"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x" id="5_star"></i></a>



$('.review_star').on("mouseover", function(){
    //get the position of the star of the data-nstar attribute
    var nstar = $(this).data("nstar");

    for (var i = 5; i >= 0; i--) {
        //if hovered star is smaller than the star (i) in the loop
        if (nstar<i) {
            $('#'.i.'_star').removeClass("alert-success");
        } else{
            $('#'.i.'_star').addClass("alert-success");
        }
    }
});

$('.review_star').on("mouseout", function(){
    $(this)removeClass("alert-success");
});


$('.review_star').on("click", function(){

    var nstar = $(this).data("nstar");

    $('#review_rating').val(star);

    for (var i = 5; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (nstar<i) {
            $('#'.i.'_star').removeClass("alert-success");
        } else{
            $('#'.i.'_star').addClass("alert-success");
        }
    }
});
```

EDIT: this should handle everything I thing? (UNTESTED)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest simplifying it *just a tad* - the snippet below works with pure Javascript, is simply to understand and easy to use. Its a mix of CSS and JS that makes it work - also note that I am setting an attribute for a star that has been marked, I'd advice you to use jQuery `addClass` and `removeClass`, but since I didn't want to work with jQuery here this solution will do.

```js
// Get all rate star UL elements
var allRateStars = document.querySelectorAll('.rate-stars');
// Use Array.prototype.slice to convert the NodeList above to a regular Array
// This enables forEach and indexOf, both features we will use
allRateStars = Array.prototype.slice.call(allRateStars);

allRateStars.forEach(function(z){
    // Get all stars in this element (as an array, not a NodeList)
    var allItems = Array.prototype.slice.call(z.querySelectorAll('li'));

    // Add event listeners to each of the LI elements
    allItems.forEach(function(a){
        a.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
            // Calculate a rating based on the index of the star you are hovering over
            // If you want a rating between 0 and 1, divide this by allItems.length
            var rating = allItems.indexOf(this);
            // Apply a class for every hovered element
            for(var i = 0; i < allItems.length; i++)
                if(i <= rating) allItems[i].className = 'hover';
                else allItems[i].className = '';
        })
        a.addEventListener('click', function(e){
            var rating = allItems.indexOf(this);
            // I am using attributes here, but - if easy - use a class
            for(var i = 0; i < allItems.length; i++)
                if(i <= rating) allItems[i].setAttribute('data-rated', 1);
                else allItems[i].removeAttribute('data-rated');
        })
    });
    
    // Remove all hovers on mouse out
    z.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e){
        allItems.forEach(function(a){ a.className = ''; });
    })
});
```

```css
ul {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  color: lightgray;
}
ul li[data-rated] {
  color: gold;
}
ul li.hover {
  color: darkgray;
}
```

```html
<ul class="rate-stars">
  <li>&#9733;</li>
  <li>&#9733;</li>
  <li>&#9733;</li>
  <li>&#9733;</li>
  <li>&#9733;</li>
</ul>

<h2>Another</h2>

<ul class="rate-stars">
  <li>&#9733;</li>
  <li>&#9733;</li>
  <li>&#9733;</li>
  <li>&#9733;</li>
  <li>&#9733;</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to simplify it

JSFIDDLE HERE http://jsfiddle.net/0cbeuqtd/

HTML

```
<div id="container">
<a href="javascript::void();" class="review_star" id="1"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x" id="1_star">x</i></a>
<a href="javascript::void();" class="review_star" id="2"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x" id="2_star">x</i></a>
<a href="javascript::void();" class="review_star" id="3"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x" id="3_star">x</i></a>
<a href="javascript::void();" class="review_star" id="4"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x" id="4_star">x</i></a>
<a href="javascript::void();" class="review_star" id="5"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-3x" id="5_star">x</i></a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.lightup { color: red }
```

JS

```
$( "body" ).data( "voted", false );
$( ".review_star" ).mouseover( function() {
    if( $( "body" ).data( "voted" ) ) {
        return false;
    }
    var $this = $( this );
    var idStr = $this.attr( "id" );
    var idNumber = parseInt( idStr );
    for( var i = 1; i <= idNumber; i++ ) {
        $( "#" + i ).addClass( "lightup" );
    }
    for( var i = idNumber + 1; i < $( ".review_star ").size(); i++ ) {
        $( "#" + i ).removeClass( "lightup" );
    }
}).click(function() {
    $( "body" ).data( "voted", true );
});
$( "#container" ).mouseout( function() {
    if( $( "body" ).data( "voted" ) ) {
        return false;
    }
    $( ".review_star" ).removeClass( "lightup" );
});
```